# awk to search multiple word pattern from one file in another file

Tags: awk, design-patterns

1st file content:

```
fruit bags    
nice things  
string guitar
```

2nd file content

```
bagsfruit  
nicefruit  
guitarstring  
simplethings  
stringguitar
```

how would i write awk program to search line by line 1st file content in 2nd file, and print only lines from 2nd file, that contain in ANY order BOTH words from 1st file..

so the result of script should be :

```
bagsfruit  
guitarstring  <--any order  
stringguitar  <--any order
```

BUT NOT any of these :

```
nicefruit  
simplethings
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[$2$1];next} ($1 in a)' first_file second_file
bagsfruit  
guitarstring
```

The code is based in examples from [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Basically it loops through the first_file and creates an array `a[]` with `fi[eld2 field1]` (that is, `$2$1`) as index. Then it checks which `field1` from second_file are in the array `a[]` and prints them.

---

#### Update

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[$2$1];a[$1$2];next} ($1 in a)' first_file seconf_file
bagsfruit  
guitarstring  
stringguitar
```

let's create two array indexes each time, `[$1$2]` and `[$2$1]`.

Comment: but that wouldnt give me stringguitar if it were in 2nd file, and it should because i need words appearing in any order.. thanks :)

Comment: Update your question with proper input / output. A workaround could be `awk 'NR == FNR{a[$2$1];a[$1$2];next} ($1 in a)'`

Comment: so if i understand well we create indexes fruitbags, bagsfruit, nicethings, thingsnice etc.. then check words from 2nd file appearing in those indexes.. but i don't understand how awk knows that it should index first file, and then after that use $1 from 2nd file?

Comment: Yes, we create indexes as you say and then checks words from 2nd file. with `awk 'NR===FNR{block1} {block2}' file1 file2`, basically awk performs `block1` for things in file1 and `block2` for things in file2. See the link I provide in my answer for a further explanation.

Comment: yes i tried that several times, but link doesn't work for me.. will try later.. one question and i wont bother anymore, prometo! :) would it be hard to extend this to 3 words in 1st file, then i get many combinations 123 132 213 231 312 321, i know i can insert them the same way but it would be ugly.. :)

Comment: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ten-awk-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls/ found here info on NR FNR trick with two file :) thanks

Comment: Try refreshing the web, the text ends up appearing. Regarding the generalization to 3 fields, I cannot figure out how it can be done in a nicer way than all combinations.

Comment: OK I see, if you get a better way please share so we all can learn :)

Comment: yes i will.. thanks very much for pushing me in some direction :)) saludos!